# What is the difference between this two ways of initializing String

Tags: java

This two codes have defferent outputs and i don't know why.

```
String a="abc";
String b="abc";
System.out.println(a==b + " " + a.equals(b));
```

The output is "true true"

```
String a="abc";
String b=new String("abc");
System.out.println(a==b + " " + a.equals(b));
```

The output is "false true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use this

```
String a="abc";
String b="abc";
```

the java creates only one object in memory which is `abc` and here a and b are pointing to same object and `==` don't check the string content instead it check the reference value. but as soon as you do this

```
String b=new String("abc");
```

java creates a new object `b` in memory which is different from `a` ,now b and a are pointing to two different objects hence if you compare contents with `equals` function result will be true but if you compare reference now, result will be false

[Read about it's usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388162/when-exactly-the-object-is-created-in-string-constant-pool-when-we-use-new-opera/39389245#39389245)

Comment: Why did you post an answer that is almost a duplicate of a previously posted answer to this question?

Comment: i was writing this answer  and he posted somewhere when i was about to finish and there is a difference , i mention about what == does and what equals does.i respect your point of view though i think it's worth posting it.

Comment: Ok they are pointing at the same object but what happens when after that I do this b="qwe";? (i guess in this moment i create new object with qwe )

Comment: it mean you are also creating a new object (if there is no string constant in the memory with "qwe" string content) and assigning it's reference to `b` because ` b="qwe";` means ` b=new String("qwe");`. String objects has this shortcut feature.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a duplicate of a large number of questions, but I will comment by saying that when you do the following:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";
```

The JVM creates a *single* String object in the constant pool which contains the String `abc`.  Hence, the `a` and `b` Strings simply point to the same string in the pool.

However, when you do the following:

```
String a = "abc";
String b = new String("abc");
```

a new object is created even though `abc` already exists in the pool.  Hence the comparison `a == b` returns false, although the contents of both these strings remains equivalent.

Comment: Comments, downvotes?  Say _something_.

Comment: To add to this: In Java, `==` compares the memory location, and `equals()` compares the content of the Strings.